# Concatenating chosen random property to object to get the array?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a few arrays in it. I am trying to return one of the arrays randomly. I have a function that returns one of the properties in the object, but I am not sure how to use it when concatenating it to the object name. For example:

Object:

```
var myObj = {
    itemOne:['blue','red','green'],
    itemTwo:['sky','grass','book'],
    itemThree:['day','month','year']
}
```

To get a certain array I would do `myObj.itemOne` which will return the first array. But I want to randomly return an array. I have a function that will return `itemOne`, `itemTwo`, or `itemThree` randomly, but when concatenating what the function returns with `myObj.` it does not work. What can I do. Here is the function:

```
function pickRandomProperty(myObj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in myObj){
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count){
           result = prop;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
```

Using what `getItemInObject` returns, I try to concatenate it with myObj to return the array. How would I do that? Here is what I have tried:

```
var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
var randProp = myObj.getItemInObject;
```

or even:

```
var randWord = myObj + '.' + getItemInObject;
```

Which returns '[object Object].itemTwo'

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xrk7b4zs/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use brackets notation:

```
var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
var randProp = myObj[getItemInObject];
//                  ^               ^
```

In JavaScript, you can refer to a property using dot notation and a property name *literal* (`obj.foo`), or brackets notation and a property name *string* (`obj["foo"]`) (or `Symbol` in ES6+, but that's not relevant here). In that second case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable reference.

**Live Example:**

```js
var myObj = {
    itemOne:['blue','red','green'],
    itemTwo:['sky','grass','book'],
    itemThree:['day','month','year']
} 

function pickRandomProperty(myObj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
    for (var prop in myObj){
        if (Math.random() < 1/++count){
           result = prop;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
var array = myObj[getItemInObject];
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(array) + "</pre>"
);
```

---

Side note: There's a much easier way to pick a random property, assuming you only care about the object's "own" properties (not ones from its prototype):

```
function pickRandomProperty(myObj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
    return keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var myObj = {
    itemOne:['blue','red','green'],
    itemTwo:['sky','grass','book'],
    itemThree:['day','month','year']
} 

function pickRandomProperty(myObj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(myObj);
    return keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
}

var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
var array = myObj[getItemInObject];
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(array) + "</pre>"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatanate strings, not code. To access an object property from a variable, use the bracket notation:

```
var randWord = myObj[getItemInObject];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrk7b4zs/2/

However, even this code will only return the object property which is an array of strings, and judging by your variable name, you might want to pick a random string from that array.

note: if for some reason you **have** to go with the dot notation, you can evaluate the concatted string using `eval` but it's not recommended in +99% of cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
console.log(getItemInObject)
var randWord = myObj[getItemInObject];
```

You need to do myObj[getItemInObject];

[Upadated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanautiyal/xrk7b4zs/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` that evaluates string as javascript code :

`var randWord = eval('myObj.' + getItemInObject);`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrk7b4zs/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can Achieve the Object Property by two Way

1. using "." operator and 2. using passing key String in [""].

You used in your code here :

```
var myObj = {
itemOne:['blue','red','green'],
itemTwo:['sky','grass','book'],
itemThree:['day','month','year']
}
```

you can get your Object Property value by two ways here

```
1. myObj.itemOne // this way you used when you know what value you want to return.

2. myObj["itemOne"] // this way you will used when you want to access you object Property in generic Way. i recommend you to use this way.
```

In your code:

var **getItemInObject** = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
this variable contained your give your **object.property name** which is you return by running Function.

```
var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
```

So You can pass this variable Like This for accessing randomly your object property value

```
var randWord = myObj[getItemInObject];
console.log(randWord);
```

I hope this Answer will help you to achieve which you want. it will give you result like.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {
    itemOne:['blue','red','green'],
    itemTwo:['sky','grass','book'],
    itemThree:['day','month','year']
} 

function pickRandomProperty(myObj) {
   var result;
   var rKey = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1) -1;
   return myObj.itemOne[rKey];
}

var getItemInObject = pickRandomProperty(myObj);
var randWord = 'myObj.itemOne' + '.' + getItemInObject;

 console.log(randWord);
```

It works!!!